# How to add SSR to existing React.js application in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I have simple React application and I want to add SSR in Express.js.

I made a bit of a gaff in the beginning and in my repository I just have a frontend folder and in it the whole React app with typescript, babel and webpack configured.

I haven't played with SSR yet, so I'm curious, if I want to make such a server and have its file in the folder next to the frontend folder, would I have to install and set all the dependencies I made inside the`frontend folder, and only then create the server.js file ?

Then in the middle of "frontend/src" I would have 2 files - index.tsx (with React.render() method), because I would like to be able to run the application also without the server. And 2nd file would be indexServer.tsx with React.hydrate() method, which would go to server.js file (i.e. would be for generating application by server). Is this concept right ?

Link to my github repo with this react app: https://github.com/poldeeek/spider-game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I want to make such a server and have its file in the folder next to the frontend folder, would I have to install and set all the dependencies I made inside the`frontend folder, and only then create the server.js file ?

You'll probably need to re-install all the dependencies if you choose to setup two separate folders like that. I would recommend putting `server.js` in `frontend/server`, which can then use the same `node_modules` as your `frontend/src/index.js` is using.

> Then in the middle of "frontend/src" I would have 2 files - index.tsx (with React.render() method), because I would like to be able to run the application also without the server. And 2nd file would be indexServer.tsx with React.hydrate() method, which would go to server.js file (i.e. would be for generating application by server). Is this concept right ?

There is no right or wrong answer here. If this setup suits your needs, then go with it. The only challenge with this setup is that you have to configure babel and webpack to point to two different files: `index.tsx` (in case you don't want the server) and `indexServer.tsx` (in case you want to include the server).